# Csv file not displaying french character even in utf-8

Tags: csv, utf-8

I have a csv file where the name (Francôis) is displayed as FRANÃƒâ€¡OIS when I open in Excel 2016. What can I do to correctly display the French character?
I tried saving as Utf-8 csv, but no luck.

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Maybe save the `csv` file with [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)?

Comment: It can often help when debugging multi-byte/UTF issues to look at the data with a hex editor to understand the bytes that are actually in the file.

Comment: If your question is about excel, you should check our sister site: https://superuser.com/ . Excel doesn't use by default UTF-8, so you should tell it that the file is UTF-8. On superusers you will find the relevant (and updated) methods to do it.

Comment: Save the file as UTF-8 w/ BOM.  Excel recognizes the BOM and will open it properly.  Without the BOM it assumes the ANSI encoding of your localized version of Windows.